# Adding reachability to iphone application gives linking errors

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.3, reachability

I keep getting these errors trying to run the Reachability.h

[image]

Comment: Post the code in twitterfeed.... the .h file

Comment: www.nathancleary.com/code.rtf

Comment: That is for the "TweetFeedDetailViewController.m"

Comment: i need the header file the ".h"

Comment: www.nathancleary.com/codeh.rtf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Project `build phases` and add the following

Under `Compile sources`, press the "+" icon and add `Reachability.m`

Under `Link Binary With Libraries` press the "+" icon and add `SystemConfiguration.framework`

[image: Check the screen shot]

**UPDATE:**

If you are receiving ARC compilation errors
You will have to disable ARC on specific files
To do that please follow the steps in this answer
[How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)

Comment: After following the above I now get this... http://www.nathancleary.com/errors.png

Comment: Thank you Omar, the ARC errors have no gone, I think I have done something else wrong as the Reachability doesn't actually work! My app just crashes instead, thanks again.

Comment: I added the framework, but I don't see that the file was added to compile resources.

Answer (score 1):

Your class is referencing [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html), but you are not adding it to your project. You should possibly add the `Reachability.m` file to the project.

Comment: Sorry Sergio not sure what you mean, I have imported both the files to my project, have I missed something?

Comment: Then check that Reachability.m has been added to your current target in its build phases...